# Understanding the confidence interval and statistical significance

Tags: probability, statistics, confidence-interval

I am struggling to understand confidence intervals and their relationships to a null hypothesis.

The basic definition of the confidence interval is: (1−α), where α is the statistical significance.

So let's say I have two cases:

1. I've allocated a 70 percent confidence level of meeting the probability of my null hypothesis, this means I have a statistical significance of of .30.
2. I've allocated a 95 percent confidence level of meeting the probability of my null hypothesis. α = .05.

Is it always better to have the case of a 95 percent confidence level, as I have the higher probability of not rejecting my null hypothesis? With the 70 percent confidence region, I always have a higher probably of falling outside the (1-α) region which rejects my null hypothesis.

To me having a 95 percent confidence is always better. Is there a reason to ever prefer 70 percent confidence interval? Would the 95 percent confidence scenario require less resources to sample from?

Comment: If you utilized a $70$% confidence interval in making your decision whether or not to reject $H_0$ then you chose your test to have size $\alpha=30$%. (Assuming your test is two tailed). Picking a level of significance in your test usually requires that you to weigh the consequences of a Type I and Type II error. Increasing the probability of a Type I error (which is $\alpha$) will effectively decrease the probability of a Type II error (which is called $\beta$). So if you picked $\alpha$ to be $30$% beforehand then the consequences in making a Type II error are probably severe.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thoughts. 95% confidence intervals seem to be, by far, the most common. In some situations where variability is extreme, people have learned they can't expect great precision. Then a 95% CI may be too long for practical use and the may be content with a 90% CI instead. (I have not seen serious applications that use 70% CIs.) // Although I don't see any direct duplicates of your question, you may want to browse the "Related questions' listed in the margin to see if they contain some points of interest.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that a 70% CI may be related to a significance level of 30%; and that a 95% CI may be related to a significance level of 5%.

Consider the following fictitious data: A sample of size $n=50$ from
a normal population with $\mu = 100$ and $\sigma = 15.$

```
set.seed(905)
x = rnorm(50, 100, 15)
```

Some summary statistics are as follows:

```
summary(x);  length(x);  sd(x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  62.76   85.32   98.02   96.99  108.22  143.80 
[1] 50           # sample size
[1] 16.28875     # sample standard deviation

stripchart(x, pch="|")
```

[image]

Suppose you want to test $H_0: \mu = 101.6$ against $H_a: \mu\ne 101.6.$
Results from a one-sample t test, `t.test` in R, are as shown below.

The P-value of the test is $0.051 > 0.05 = 5\%$ so you (just barely)
miss rejecting at the 5% level. Also, a 95% CI for $\mu$ is
$(92.36, 101.62),$ which does (just barely) contain the hypothetical value $101.6,$ You can say that the 95% CI is an interval of values of $\mu$ wich cannot be rejected at the 5% level. [95% CI's are the 'default' in R; if you want some other level of confidence, you have to say so.]

```
t.test(x, mu = 101.6)

        One Sample t-test

data:  x
t = -2, df = 49, p-value = 0.05106
alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 101.6
95 percent confidence interval:
  92.36363 101.62205
sample estimates:
mean of x 
 96.99284
```

By contrast, if you specify a 70% CI, here are results from 't.test'.
The P-value is again $0.0501,$ But if you want to test at the 30% level,
you can reject because $0.0501 < 0.30 = 30\%.$

Notice that the 70% CI is much shorter than the former 95% Ci. In
particular the 70% CI $(94.58, 99.41)$ does not (even nearly) contain the hypothetical value $101,6.$

```
t.test(x, mu = 101.6, conf.lev=.7)

        One Sample t-test

data:  x
t = -2, df = 49, p-value = 0.05106
alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 101.6
70 percent confidence interval:
 94.57980 99.40588
sample estimates:
mean of x 
 96.99284
```

*Note:* The significance level of a test specifies the probability
of (falsely) rejecting a true parameter value. A 30% significance level indicates a willingness to make that mistake almost a third of the time. For my fictitious data we happen to know the true value $\mu = 100.$ Because the 70% CI does not cover $100,$ we know that the t test would wrongly reject $H_0: \mu=100$ for my fictitious data. [With real data is very rare ever to know the exact true parameter value so one won't know when a false rejection is made.]